# Can not find nuget package Urho.iOS

Tags: xamarin, f#, xamarin.ios, nuget, xamarin-studio

I downloaded urhosharp and try to run the f# helloworld example:

https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/cross-platform/urho/urho-fsharp/HelloWorldUrhoFsharp

I get a warning:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.3/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets: 
Warning: Reference 'Urho.iOS' not resolved (HelloWorldUrho1)
```

And can not find Urho.iOS in the nuget package browser, and no info via google.

How do I get the Urho.iOS package added to Xamarin studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I get the Urho.iOS package added to Xamarin studio?

You are looking for the `UrhoSharp` package as it contains the Xamarin.iOS10 `Urho.dll` assembly.

```
├── UrhoSharp.1.0.410
│   ├── UrhoSharp.1.0.410.nupkg
│   ├── build
~~~
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── MonoAndroid
│   │   │   └── Urho.dll
│   │   ├── Xamarin.iOS10
│   │   │   └── Urho.dll
│   │   ├── net45
│   │   │   └── Urho.dll
│   │   └── portable-net45+win8+monoandroid+monotouch+Xamarin.iOS10
│   │       └── Urho.dll
│   └── native
~~~
```

#### Note:

Check to make sure that the packages were restored properly in your solution. The `packages.config` originally references version `1.0.218` which is **no** longer available via Nuget and thus will error out when trying to do a restore.

Your `packages.config` should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="UrhoSharp" version="1.0.410" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
</packages>
```

Comment: yes both the 28 and 40 versions where in packages.config, now the warning is gone